# how to add multiple flutter modules built into aar into an existing android project?

Tags: android, performance, flutter, aar

I have tried integrating multiple flutter modules after building the `aar` file for both modules.

But once I include the dependencies , i am getting class conflicts in the gradle build process of android.

How do I fix this ? How do I add multiple flutter modules into a single android app ?

Answer (score 5):

Actually the flutter doesn't have support you can follow up this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39707